# Renewing LetsEncrypt SSL certificate needs port 80 - can I redirect port 80 from another server?

Tags: ssl, iis, lets-encrypt

I'm running IIS 7 on an old Windows Server 2008. While this machine is my main web host, I host a site on another (Lubuntu) server on the same LAN. This site has an SSL certificate which has been generated using LetsEncrypt. I need to renew this certificate every 90 days using a utility called certbot, but this needs to use port 80.
As I currently have port 80 on my router redirected to my main (IIS) web host, this means I have to temporarily redirect port 80 on the router to my Lubuntu server every time my SSL cert is due for renewal.
I was wondering if there was any way that I could configure my main IIS web host to redirect requests on port 80 to my Lubuntu host if the domain name requested was the one hosted on that Lubuntu host?

Comment: If the domain name requested is the one hosted on Lubuntu, why not map the domain name to the Lubuntu IP in router?

Comment: My router doesn't allow mapping of domain names to internal nodes - only port forwarding. Since all of my other websites are on a different machine I have port 80 directed to that machine.

Comment: If so, which server IP does your router map the domain name hosted in Lubuntu to?

Comment: The router is not able to map domain names. It is only able to forward ports to specific internal IP addresses.